# How to give an input wav file to pocket sphinx

Tags: cmusphinx

Is there some command line utility of pocket sphinx or cmu sphinx to convert a .wav file to text?

pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm  -lm  -dict  will do. But I don't want to keep speaking the same sentence again and again.

Answer (score 10):

`pocketsphinx_continuous` starting from version 0.8 has option `-infile` which you can use to decode a file. File must be in a specific format: 16khz 16bit mono wav file

```
 pocketsphinx_continuous -infile file.wav
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see this -infile argument in man file. Moreover, I get the following error. FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 153: Failed to calibrate voice activity detection.
I have the input file in 8k sample rate. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, if you want to decode 8khz audio file you need to add an option '-samprate 8000'. Also make sure you are using the correct acoustic model for the audio you are trying to decode.

Comment: Even with -samprate 8000, i get the same error :( "FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 153: Failed to calibrate voice activity detection"

Comment: share the file you are trying to recognize

Comment: I had this same problem, and it was solved by creating a larger file, with more silence at the beginning. From what I read in the Sphinx code, it seems that this calibration process is to calibrate what is silence and what isn't. Since I had a very small audio file (only three words, about a second), I deduced it needs more data to "calibrate" the silence.

Comment: In recent versions this issue was fixed, you don't need to add silence anymore.

Comment: This hasn't worked for a long time. You need to specify an acoustic model.

Comment: If models are properly installed, you do not need to specify the model path on Linux. On Windows you always need to specify the path since there is no "installation" step there.